# How to stop adding delete button to first form in django formset?

Tags: javascript, django

I am creating a dynamic form using formsets. So basically when user click on "Add Field" button a new form will be created and when user click on trash icon the form should be removed !

Now the problem is that, delete icon is displaying on first default form also so if the click on the icon the default form also gets removed ! How to add delete icon on the cloned forms ?

```
<script>
function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, ndx) {
        var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+)');
        var replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx;
        if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", $(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex, replacement));
        if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
        if (el.name) el.name = el.name.replace(id_regex, replacement);
    }

    function addForm(btn, prefix) {
        var formCount = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
        var row = $('.dynamic-form:first').clone(true).get(0);
        $(row).removeAttr('id').insertAfter($('.dynamic-form:last')).children('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
        $(row).children().not(':last').children().each(function() {
            updateElementIndex(this, prefix, formCount);
            $(this).val('');
        });
        $(row).find('.delete-row').click(function() {
            deleteForm(this, prefix);
        });
        $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(formCount + 1);
        return false;
    }

    function deleteForm(btn, prefix) {
        $(btn).parents('.dynamic-form').remove();
        var forms = $('.dynamic-form');
        $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(forms.length);
        for (var i=0, formCount=forms.length; i<formCount; i++) {
            $(forms.get(i)).children().not(':last').children().each(function() {
                updateElementIndex(this, prefix, i);
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
<script>
$(function () {
        $('.add-row').click(function() {
            return addForm(this, 'form');
        });
        $('.delete-row').click(function() {
            return deleteForm(this, 'form');
        })
    })
</script>
```

This is the snippets am using, i need to add

```
<a id="remove-{{ form.prefix }}-row" href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete-row">Delete <em class="icon ni ni-trash-fill text-danger fs-15px"></em></a>
```

on the cloned form alone, default form should not contain this ! Please help

Answer (score 0):

Delegate

Change 'tr' to 'form' if it is a form or  '.row' for whatever a '.row' is

```js
$("#tb").on('click', '.delete-row', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove()
});
```

```css
tbody tr:first-child button.delete-row {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="tb">
    <tr>
      <td>Row 0</td>
      <td><button class="delete-row">Click 0</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
      <td><button class="delete-row">Click 1</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
      <td><button class="delete-row">Click 2</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How this gonna remove the delete button on default form ? The first form should not have delete button and once a new form is added then the new form should only have delete button !

Comment: Use css to hide first of type

Comment: ya but how to find if its first ? ```{{ form.prefix }}``` always stays 0

Comment: @sixovov947 Please show some RENDERED HTML so I can show you how

Comment: See updated css